# strage thing happening on android google map web app

Tags: android, web-applications, mobile, google-maps-api-3

If you look below, I have a partial screenshot of my web app designed for mobile devices. On android I get a peculiar green shape that looks like a bunch of characters piled up on each other. I upgraded to Ice Cream sandwitch but the same thing is happening. And it's ONLY on the page where I have my map.

Has anyone seen anything like this or know what might be causing it?

It's adjacent the Log Off link in a dark forest green.

[image]

## Update:

I narrowed it down to Google Maps API v3. It happens when I call the constructor, but I still don't know how to fix it or get rid of it.

```js
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    'zoom': 16,
    'center': new google.maps.LatLng(39.205316, -96.305485),
    'mapTypeId': google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID,
    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    },
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_BOTTOM,
        style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    }, 
    streetViewControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    },             
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    }                      
});
```

## Update #2:

Tried debugging it with Chrome Mobile but it's not showing up. Only shows up in Android ICS browser.

---

## SOLUTION:

Looks like the Android ICS browser does not play nice with CSS `text-indent: -9999em;`

For my logo element I had the following html:

```html
<hgroup>
    <h1><a href="Default.aspx#main">Company Name</a></h1>
</hgroup>
```

```css
/* Logo */
header hgroup {
    background: url("../imgs/logo_143x60.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 6px;
    width: 312px;
}
header hgroup h1 a {
    text-indent: -9999em;
    display: block;
    height: 60px;
    width: auto;
}
header hgroup h3  {
    text-indent: -9999em;
    height: 0;
}
```

I simply removed the text `Company Name`, problem solved.

Comment: Glad you got there in the end capdragon. I'll bear that text-indent issue in mind for future. (+1)

Comment: Wouldn't have gotten there if I hadn't followed your suggestion about testing it on different phones. Doing that made me realize it was on ALL pages, not just the map one. That narrowed down the possibilities to only elements that are common throught the site (logo was the first thing i checked).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a link I'm kinda working blind here, but IF it's not something directly caused by your code - I'd take a wild guess and say it could be the result of an app on your device? For example I know some sat nav apps turn addresses into hyperlinks (to open up the sat nav app). As it's on the page that has a map, this theory sounds plausable.

Evaluate the offending element in Firebug/Web Inspector for more clues.

**Update**
Following revelations that it only happens in the Android browser, I'd try a few steps to help narrow down the root causation.

Get your friends/colleagues/emulators to replicate the issue. If it is intermittent, or only applicable to your own device - this sounds like the behaviour of a rogue app parsing text into a link or something similar. Knowing which offending app it is will help track down where the problem lies.

Another option would be to find elements that have a *color* style of the dark green color in your stylesheet. Change the *color* to pink, and keep reducing the scope of the CSS selector until only that one element is pink - that will give you indication as to where this element has come from and what it is (I hope). This is quite a laborious process though.

There may be better ways to debug something like this in Android browser, but unfortunately I don't know about them. Good luck!

Comment: (+1)Yeah... kind of like the skype application, it translates phone numbers... I'll look into it. But I can't use Firebug because it does not happen on my desktop. Only on android mobile browser. I'll start commenting things out block by block and see if it disappears.

Comment: Try remote debugging with Chrome Mobile: https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/debugging

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not showing up on Chrome Mobile. Only on the Android ICS browser.

Comment: Updated answer, I hope it helps a bit?

Comment: Very good suggestions. I'll get back to you tomorrow with the results

Comment: Okay, so it IS happening on 2 other androids (Default browser). And The dark green comes from a catch all CSS `a:link, a:visited {color:#285935;}`. :/